# How to resolve Python KeyError elegantly (Python csv library)

Tags: python, json, csv, keyerror

I have written a basic web scraper in Python using the lxml and JSON libraries. The below code snippet details how I currently write to CSV:

```
with open(filepath, "ab") as f:

                write = csv.writer(f) 

                try:
                    write.writerow(["allhomes",
                                    statenum,
                                    statesubnum,
                                    suburbnum,
                                    listingnum,
                                    listingsurlstr,
                                    '',  # fill this in! should be 'description'
                                    node["state"],
                                    node["suburb"],
                                    node["postcode"],
                                    node["propertyType"],
                                    node["bathrooms"],
                                    node["bedrooms"],
                                    node["parking"],
                                    pricenode,
                                    node["photoCount"],
                                    node2["pricemin"],
                                    node2["pricemax"],
                                    node2["pricerange"]])
                except KeyError, e:
                    try:
                        write.writerow(["allhomes",
                                        statenum,
                                        statesubnum,
                                        suburbnum,
                                        listingnum,
                                        listingsurlstr,
                                        '',  # fill this in! should be 'description'
                                        node["state"],
                                        node["suburb"],
                                        node["postcode"],
                                        node["propertyType"],
                                        '',
                                        node["bedrooms"],
                                        node["parking"],
                                        pricenode,
                                        node["photoCount"],
                                        node2["pricemin"],
                                        node2["pricemax"],
                                        node2["pricerange"]])
                    except KeyError, e:
                            errorcount += 1
                            with open(filepath, "ab"):  #
                                write = csv.writer(f)
                                write.writerow(["Error: invalid dictionary field key: %s" % e.args,
                                                statenum,
                                                statesubnum,
                                                suburbnum,
                                                listingnum,
                                                listingsurlstr])
                    pass
                pass
```

The problem is such that if a certain node does not exist (most commonly the Bathrooms node) I have to try again by replacing the Bathrooms node with a blank value, or subsequently give up the entire row of data. My current approach is to try again and write the row by removing the Bathrooms node, but this is messy (and does not fix KeyErrors with other nodes).

How can I pass over writing a single node in this situation if it does not exist or does not contain any data, without sacrificing the whole entry?

Many thanks.

Comment: Web scraping of any size almost always results in messy data, it seems. Is there a way you can avoid this need for matching keys some where earlier in the code?

Comment: Haha this is true. You're almost certainly right - I was just unable to find a good, repeatable way to do so

Comment: Is `node` a dictionary? If so, you can use [get](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use keys like this, one way I've used in the past with web scraping was to create a wrapper that handled the errors, then returned the value.

```
def get_node(name, node):
    try:
        val = node[name]
    except KeyError:
        val = 'na'
    return val

write.writerow(['allhomes',
                get_node('bathrooms', node),
                ...
               ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue above but with `DictWriter`. +1 for @Jeff's answer helping me out. Had to slightly modify it to handle Dicts, but hopefully helps someone else:

```
def check_val(item_value):
    try:
        if my_data.get(item_value):
            val = something.get(item_value)
    except:
        val = None

    return val

writer.writerow({

                 'item_key' : check_val('item_value'),
                 ...
})
```

By checking (via the `check_val` function) whether or not the value exists first, you can avoid the KeyError if it doesn't. You can also extend the logic under the `if` statement to extract data from nested lists and dictionaries if you have data where they may or may not exist, which is really useful too.